# Finding matching string among two columns from two different tables

Tags: string, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

**select * from all_tables** fetches me all the tables in database

```
   Table A
    Name     Shortform
    Generate GNRT
    Support  SPRT  
    and so onn..
```

There are around 100 table names and 50 English names along with shortforms
Each table name is created using shortforms for example SELECT * FROM GNRT_SPRT
If for a new person tries to create table and does not follow the shortforms then those table name should be fetched in new  table named results.

```
FOR example:      
select * from gnrte_sche
```

The above example does not match the short forms hence that table name should be inserted in a new table named results. I need to check for all tables by using the select * from all_tables

```
-output-
Table Results
Diff_tables--column name
gnrte_sche
```

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you have a table called "A" that defines all the English words being considered and a short form for each?  Thanks

Comment: @alexgibbs yes absolutely

Comment: Ok thanks.  Just to confirm, you'd like to find all the TABLE_NAMEs in ALL_TABLES that are NOT made up of SHORTFORMs?

Comment: @alexgibbs yes .. I mean all those which are not made of short forms or which are not matching the Shortform column from table A should be fetched in different table

Comment: Thanks Techie.  I'm not quite sure what is meant by "fetched in a different table", but I'll post something that will find you all the TABLEs in ALL_TABLES that are not composed of SHORTFORMs.  Can you let me know meantime what you mean by 'fetched in a different table'?

Comment: @alexgibbs yes! Fetched in a different table means..For example I have a table named gener_sup Now this table will be added in select * from all_tables after its creation but when I check against the shortforms  it is not matching because shortform for generate is gnrt and for support is sprt. So ideally table name should be gnrt_sprt since table creating is not matching with shortforms hence that table name(gener_sup ) will be displayed in a different table

Comment: Thanks Techie.  An example has been posted.  If you can review/try it out and let me know any questions that would be great

Comment: @alexgibbs sure Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

**Edited** to include saving mismatches.
This is not tuned, and there are likely other simpler solutions, but the below may do what you are looking for.

This block will print out any table names that are not composed of only `SHORTFORM` words and underscores, with the first (only) non-shortform found.  It will also save all the matches to an example table called `NON_SHORTFORM`.  It allows prefix and suffix underscores, and allows the "$" character, so long is it is in a SHORTFORM.

This will read the `SHORTFORM`s from `TABLE A`, and evaluate everything in ALL_TABLES to check whether each is made of `SHORTFORM`s.  When a malformed `TABLE_NAME` is encountered, it will print it out via `DBMS_OUTPUT` along with the mismatched word and save a record of the mismatch.

First, create an example `A TABLE`:

```
CREATE TABLE A(
  NAME VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  SHORTFORM VARCHAR2(30) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO A VALUES('Generate','GNRT');
INSERT INTO A VALUES('Support','SPRT');
INSERT INTO A VALUES('Hobbit','HOBT');
INSERT INTO A VALUES('Wookie','WOKI');
INSERT INTO A VALUES('Adventure','AVNTR');
```

Then create some example `TABLE`s to check

```
CREATE TABLE GNRT_SPRT(X NUMBER);
CREATE TABLE WOKI_SPRT(X NUMBER);
CREATE TABLE HOBT_WOKI_AVNTR(X NUMBER);
CREATE TABLE ROBOTS(X NUMBER);
CREATE TABLE GNRTE_SCHE(X NUMBER);
```

Then create a `TABLE` to save the mismatches (Please note, this only allows saving one mismatch per TABLE.  If your use case is different, this can be adjusted as needed):

```
CREATE TABLE NON_SHORTFORM(
OWNER VARCHAR2(128) NOT NULL,
TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2(128) NOT NULL,
MISMATCHED_WORD VARCHAR2(128) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT NON_SHORTFORM_PK PRIMARY KEY (OWNER, TABLE_NAME));
```

Then create a `BLOCK` that will do the evaluation (could be a `FUNCTION`, etc. if preferred).  Please note, this allows "$" and numbers.  If you want to exclude those, the below could also be adapted:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE V_STRING_LIST IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(128);
  V_SHORT_FORM_SET V_STRING_LIST;
  V_SHORT_FORM_MATCHED NUMBER(1,0) := 0;
  V_TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2(128);
  V_TABLE_NAME_WORK_SPACE VARCHAR2(128);
  V_TABLE_TOKEN VARCHAR2(128);
BEGIN
  SELECT SHORTFORM BULK COLLECT INTO V_SHORT_FORM_SET FROM A;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('MALFORMED TABLE-NAMES:');
<<TABLE_NAME_LOOP>>
FOR TABLE_POINTER IN (  SELECT ALL_TABLES.OWNER, ALL_TABLES.TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES   WHERE ALL_TABLES.TABLE_NAME <> 'A')
  LOOP
    V_TABLE_NAME_WORK_SPACE := REGEXP_REPLACE(TABLE_POINTER.TABLE_NAME,'((^[_]{1,})|([_]{1,}$))',NULL);
  <<SHORT_FORM_LOOP>>
    LOOP
      V_TABLE_NAME_WORK_SPACE := REGEXP_REPLACE(V_TABLE_NAME_WORK_SPACE,'((^[_]{1,})|([_]{1,}$))',NULL);
      EXIT WHEN NOT (REGEXP_LIKE(COALESCE(V_TABLE_NAME_WORK_SPACE,'!'),'^[_A-Z0-9$]{1,}$'));
      V_TABLE_TOKEN := REGEXP_SUBSTR(V_TABLE_NAME_WORK_SPACE,'^[A-Z0-9$]{1,}');
      V_TABLE_NAME_WORK_SPACE := REGEXP_REPLACE(V_TABLE_NAME_WORK_SPACE,'^[A-Z0-9$]{1,}',NULL);
      SELECT COUNT(*) INTO V_SHORT_FORM_MATCHED FROM A
      WHERE A.SHORTFORM = V_TABLE_TOKEN;

      IF NOT V_SHORT_FORM_MATCHED = 1
      THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(UTL_LMS.FORMAT_MESSAGE('Table-Name:%s,Mismatched-Shortform:%s',TABLE_POINTER.TABLE_NAME,V_TABLE_TOKEN));
MERGE INTO NON_SHORTFORM USING (
    SELECT TABLE_POINTER.OWNER AS OWNER,
    TABLE_POINTER.TABLE_NAME AS TABLE_NAME,
    V_TABLE_TOKEN AS MISMATCHED_WORD
    FROM DUAL) CANDIDATE_MISMATCH
  ON (NON_SHORTFORM.OWNER = CANDIDATE_MISMATCH.OWNER
  AND NON_SHORTFORM.TABLE_NAME = CANDIDATE_MISMATCH.TABLE_NAME)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET NON_SHORTFORM.MISMATCHED_WORD = CANDIDATE_MISMATCH.MISMATCHED_WORD
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (OWNER, TABLE_NAME, MISMATCHED_WORD)
  VALUES (CANDIDATE_MISMATCH.OWNER, CANDIDATE_MISMATCH.TABLE_NAME, CANDIDATE_MISMATCH.MISMATCHED_WORD);
        EXIT;
      END IF;
    END LOOP SHORT_FORM_LOOP;
  END LOOP TABLE_NAME_LOOP;
END;
/
```

Then run it (I'm expecting it to ignore `GNRT_SPRT`, `WOKI_SPRT`, etc. since they have SHORTFORMs, but to list `ROBOTS` and `GNRTE_SCHE`:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
-- CODE BLOCK FROM GOES HERE
MALFORMED TABLE-NAMES:
... other TABLEs omitted ...
Table-Name:ROBOTS,Mismatched-Shortform:ROBOTS
Table-Name:GNRTE_SCHE,Mismatched-Shortform:GNRTE
```

And checking the saved mismatches (Note In this example, *Only* the first mismatch found is saved.  If you want to save every mismatch, the above block would need to be updated accordingly):

```
SELECT * FROM NON_SHORTFORM;
OWNER  TABLE_NAME  MISMATCHED_WORD
-- Other records omitted
LIMS   ROBOTS      ROBOTS
LIMS   GNRTE_SCHE  GNRTE
```

Comment: The first loop shall split the table name and second loop shall compare it with shortforms??

Comment: All the tables you have created!! well inbuilt metadata select * from all_tables shall give me all the tables why did you create again?

Comment: Thanks @Techie The first loop iterates through each table name.  The second loop checks it is composed only of shortforms and underscores.  I created extra tables to test the code and show the procedure in action--to make sure that tables composed of shortforms are skipped but those without not made of shortforms are flagged.

Comment: Can the output in dbms_output.put_line be saved in a table having two columns?

Comment: @Techie sure thing it can.  I'll update with an example.

Comment: insert into results_utility(diff_table_name, mismatched_string) values(V_TABLE_NAME_LIST(TABLE_LOOP),V_TABLE_TOKEN); 
Iam trying this but its not fetching any rows

Comment: @Techie please try the update I provided and let me know if this is the sort of thing you had in mind.  it creates a table NON_SHORTFORM and saves the mismatches there.